# Java Console to GUI

Tags: java, user-interface, console

I have a question answering (QA) system which is console application based on openephyra but i need to develop it into gui application as openephyra runs on console application.

Is it possible I redirect them to GUI? If yes, how should I develop?

It might contain two textareas for the user to enter the question and display the answer, when user clicks the go button.

Comment: I think that most important question for you to answer is this: are your current classes well-configured OOP classes, or does it mostly consist of static methods?  If the former, then creating a decent GUI with your code should be easier.  The next issue is that your goal should be to create a well behaved event-driven GUI, not a console app that's simply displayed in a GUI.  The details of our answers will depend on the details of your problem, so you'll need to give us more information for us to be able to give you better help.  Good luck and welcome to SOF.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.ephyra.info/ appears to have alot of tutorials regarding this. Might be worth starting there and working through some of them.

Comment: thanks for your reply. but the opensource ephyra contains only console application that runs on eclipse if i'm not mistaken.

Comment: Ah, apologies. I miss understood your question. Could you elaborate on it? (Best way is to edit your question) Do you currently have any form of solution built? (Console or otherwise)

Comment: It's ok.  I am doing a QA system for my school project which involving question processing and answer extraction like openephyra. But i want to develop it and display it in GUI, so is it possible i redirect them to GUI interface in easier way?